# how can i fix this error in angular component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, frontend, components

[{
"resource": "/c:/Users/User/Desktop/ang/firstapp/src/app/app.component.ts",
"owner": "typescript",
"code": "7016",
"severity": 8,
"message": "Could not find a declaration file for module 'tslib'. 'c:/Users/User/Desktop/ang/firstapp/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.\n  Try `npm i --save-dev @types/tslib` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'tslib';`",
"source": "ts",
"startLineNumber": 3,
"startColumn": 1,
"endLineNumber": 7,
"endColumn": 3
}]

fix it i am biggener at angular

Comment: what command are you running when you get that error?  did you try the recommendation: npm i --save-dev @types/tslib.   also if you have not done so yet youll have to run "npm install" from the command line on the directory where package.json exists.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

- Checking versions (Node, ...)
- Remove package-lock, yarn lock
- Remove node-module
- Install new node-module